# Question about NSLog and where to handle a loading file

Tags: iphone, file-upload, nslog

In my code i am building a Data Core database out of a .txt file. Currently i have that file on the desktop and have a hard-coded path to that file. I am also tracking the load of the database with NSLog-statement that shows in the terminal when i load a new database. The build & analyze states that the parameters that i use for tracking in the NSLog's "Value stored to xx is never read". However, i do use xx in the NSLog to count the records i am loading.

I am using a secret and very long and specific word in an input field to start the load of the database. This field is normally used for something else.

I have the following questions:

- Is the "Value stored to xx is never read" considered a leak? I guess not.
- Is there a problem when launching the app to have the NSLog and the xx still in the code or should i commented it out?
- I have read in Apples documentation that it is not allowed to reference outside of the bundle, i would guess that if i want to use this method i should place the .txt in the bundle as well?
- As i do not want the .txt file to be in the package what is the recommendation for managing the load of the database? Should i load the database and then maybe commented out all related code in the code i ship to app-store to remove the references out side the app or is there a better way?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

- "Value stored to xx is never read" message

This message is not a leak. It's a hint that you're setting a variable to a value and then never, ever reading that value (thus setting the variable in the first place is meaningless). Example:

```
- (void) fooFun {
    int i = 1;
    NSLog(@"Hello: %d", i);
    i = 3; // <- value stored to i is never read (thus this line is redundant)
    return;
}
```

- Problem when launching apps with NSLogs in them

No, Apple does recommend removing NSLogs but it's not required AFAIK. I may be wrong, as I am using a macro that removes all NSLogs from a release build. IIRC, this blog post described it for me: http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2009/03/23/114/

- Referencing outside of the bundle

This is an odd question. If you intend to put your app on the app store, other people will most likely grab it and they won't have your file. Nor does the iPhone itself have access to your desktop. For argument's sake, though, you would probably create a setting in your app which let users define a path to where this file is located.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Kalle, tx for you answer. Well, the meaning is that noone except me should have access to the .txt file.

Comment: So it's sort of a database that the app uses but that only you can see and modify? Bundling it with the app is about as safe as you can go. Putting it online, people will be able to fetch it from a browser. If people unpack your app data and check, they'll find the file but that's about it. You may want to look into encrypting the file inside the iPhone bundle and then somehow unencrypting it when needed, but that too has its drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks Kalle, well the situation is that i am only want to use the .txt file for one thing and that as my source for the database. I write my data in the .txt file and then load the database from there. Ideal would be not to have the .txt file with the app when i upload it.

Comment: Without more information or specifics, I can't give you any more suggestions than I already have. It sounds like you want to rethink the .txt file deal, though.

Comment: Kalle, I am struggling a bit with how to populate the DB from outside of the application. The current way i do this is 1.) type in the .txt file, 2.) use a secret password in the app to load the DB from the .txt file currently residing on my desktop. BTW, i am also Swedish.